# Using FlowDroid programmatically with the Soot framework?

Tags: java, analysis, dataflow, soot, program-slicing

I am working on a Java project which aims to perform **forward slicing technique** using **the Soot framework** .

The global picture of my project is to convert some bytecode files to **Jipmle form** and then perform forward slicing technique accordingly, however, I am new to the Soot framework, so I have done some research and found that the Soot framework doesn't support any kind of slicing techniques.

I wonder if I can use **FlowDroid** or any other to perform forward slicing technique in my project programmatically?

could anyone point me in the right direction to get started with this?

Thanks in advance.

ANter.

Answer (score 0):

it is indeed possible to use FlowDroid programmatically.
To do so, you should first initialise Soot (the framework on which FlowDroid is built) by setting up soot options and loading necessary classes.

Then, you can use the `runInfoflow();` method of FlowDroid to run it programmatically inside your own program. 
Take a look at this repo for an example : 
https://github.com/secure-software-engineering/DroidForce/blob/6d89d137cc04a44d5669e2256b4790976fe861b6/Instrumentation-PEP/src/de/ecspride/Main.java

Best

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, appreciate it.